# Omnibar extension opening a mailto: link

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have created an omnibar extension that searches our company crm. I want to allow a user to do the following:-

CRM email:ross dargan

and when they press enter I e-mail the user. I have the suggestions working great, and I am successfully getting the uri out for the mail to, however calling this code (from the samples) with a uri does nothing:-

```
navigate('mailto:ross.dargan@.....com');

function navigate(url) {
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function (tab) {
        chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, { url: url });
    });
}
```

I get no error - but the default mail program doesn't pop up - I know I can get the tab, and insert scripts, so I could probably do something like this:-

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function (tab) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code: 'window.location=mailto:ross.dargan.....com'});
    });
```

but the above code will only work if I give my extension access to every host which I can do but would rather not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an iFrame in your background page seems to work....

```
var mailtoFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
document.documentElement.appendChild(mailtoFrame);

function mailto(link){
mailtoFrame.setAttribute('src', link);
}

mailto("mailto:ross.dargan@google.com");
```

Comment: I'm an idiot - it looks like mailto links just don't work on windows 8 cp. Should have tried that first - but it looks like tel: doesn't work using the above, so I'll try your method for that!